# Catching all click events, obscuring other contained elements

Tags: html, css

```
<app-drawer-layout fullbleed>

    <!-- Drawer content -->
    <app-drawer swipe-open>I have the following code:

      <iron-selector selected="[[page]]" class="drawer-list" role="navigation" attr-for-selected="name" id="menu-main" on-iron-select="_selectionEvent" >

        <!-- First link. With overlapping DIV -->
        <a style="position: relative" name="view1" href="/page/view1">
          <div drawer-toggle style="position: absolute;top:0;bottom:0;left:0;right:0"></div>
          <iron-icon icon="home"></iron-icon>
          <span>View One</span>
        </a>

        <!-- Second link. Drawer only goes away when the click is on the span -->
        <a name="view2" href="/page/view2">
          <iron-icon icon="question-answer"></iron-icon>
          <span drawer-toggle >View Two</span>
        </a>

        <!-- Third link. Works but it's a lot of typing... -->
        <a drawer-toggle name="view3" href="/page/view3">
          <iron-icon drawer-toggle icon="work"></iron-icon>
          <span drawer-toggle>View Three</span>
        </a>
      </iron-selector>
      ...
```

It's for a polymer element, but that's besides the point of this question. What is important is that iron-selector listens to clicks, and that when a click is done on an element with the `drawer-toggle` attribute, app-drawer-layout retracts the drawer (which is what I want).

The problem in `view2` is that the drawer will only ever retract when you click *exactly* on the writing in the span. `view3` is a lot of typing, but that also works.
`view1` fixes the problem by creating a `div` that will overlap all of the others. So, just THAT needs to set `drawer-toggle`.

Now... is that horrible? Will it have side effects I cannot predict? Is there a nice alternative?

Comment: I think you should use view3 but to <a> element add display: block or inline-block. So you don't need to add drawer-toggle in child items.

Comment: Tried it, but no joy. The click event is still originating by the sub-elements